# ZF2 validator messages i18n

Tags: php, validation, localization, zend-framework2

I localize product, and i'm newb in PHP,ZF2. I have .PO/.MO files with english and japanese translation. How to configure ZF2 to use these .mo translation in all `library\Zend\Validator\*` files instead of default messages e.g 

    `protected $messageTemplates = array(
        self::NOT_GREATER => "The input is not greater than '%min%'",
        self::NOT_GREATER_INCLUSIVE => "The input is not greater or equal than '%min%'"
    );`

I've read these [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.html#translating-messages) but it doesnt help me.
I'm have custom Translator which extends MvcTranslator and config looks like:
```

````
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases'   => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        // ...
        'MvcTranslator' => function ($services) {
            $config     = $services->get('config');
            $config     = isset($config['translator']) ? $config['translator'] : array();
            $translator = \Application\I18n\Translator::factory($config);

            $translator->setEscaper(new \Application\Escaper\Escaper);

            // add event listener for context fallback on missing translations
            $translator->enableEventManager();
            $translator->getEventManager()->attach(
                $translator::EVENT_MISSING_TRANSLATION,
                array($translator, 'handleMissingTranslation')
            );

            // establish default locale settings
            $translator->setLocale($translator->getLocale() ?: 'en_US');
            $translator->setFallbackLocale($translator->getFallbackLocale() ?: 'en_US');

            // try to guess locale from browser language header (using intl if available)
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])
                && (!isset($config['detect_locale']) || $config['detect_locale'] !== false)
            ) {
                $locale = extension_loaded('intl')
                    ? \Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])
                    : str_replace('-', '_', current(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])));

                $translator->setLocale(strlen($locale) ? $locale : $translator->getLocale());
            }

            return $translator;
        },
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale'                    => 'en_US',
    'detect_locale'             => true,
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo'
        ),
    ),
),
```
````

I thought i should put `Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);`
somewhere there..but nothing changed..Should i write some code in validators or what ?

Comment: Does this custom Translator translate anything? +And you know you have to add _"The input is not greater than '%min%'"_ as key with translated value (_"Ahah, lower than '%min%'"_) to your files?

Comment: Yes this translator works (it just adds some methods to embedded translator). Already localized almost everything in project inside views, controllers, models, Filters. But stuck with these validators..